# jScrollPane setVisible doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a show button to show a `JTable` on click but the table is not visible. 
Note: when I remove the `JScrollPane` the code works properly but the header of the table is not shown, so any help please to make this code work properly without removing the `JScrollPane`

```
        import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

        import javax.swing.JButton;
        import javax.swing.JFrame;
        import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
        import javax.swing.JTable;
        import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

        public class Training extends JFrame {

            public Training() {

                getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                JTable table = new JTable();
                table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] { { "joe", "joe" },
                        { "mickel", "mickel" }, }, new String[] { "LastName",
                        "FirstName" }));
                final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
                pane.setVisible(false);
                getContentPane().add(pane);

                JButton btn = new JButton("show");
                add(btn);
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pane.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Training app = new Training();
                app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                app.setSize(600, 600);
                app.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After `pane.setVisible(true);` add the following:

```
getContentPane().validate();
getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: Is it expected behavior? Why isn't `pane.setVisible(true);` alone sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

A few things to note:

- Never extends `JFrame` class unnecessarily, or else you might need to extend another class which is very necessary but in java a single class may not *extend* more than one other class (no multiple inheritance).
- Always create Swing components on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block.
- Do not use `setSize(..)`  call `JFrame#pack()` before setting `JFrame` visible
- No need for `getContentPane.add(..)` or `getContentPane().setLayout(..)`, simply call `add(..)` or `setLayout(..)` on `JFrame` instance as these calls are fowared to the *contentPane*.
- The problem you have is you do not *refresh* you frame/container after setting pane visible. I disagree with @Dan. Do not use `validate()` (`getContentPane()` is not necesarry either) rather:

  ```
  revalidate();
  repaint();
  ```

as `revalidate()` covers `validate()`. Also validate is used when new `JComponent`s are added to a visible component, whereas `revalidate()` is used when `JComponent` is removed/added from a visible component.

Here is a fixed version of the code with the above implemented:

[image]

After button pressed:

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Training {

    private JFrame frame;

    public Training() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{"joe", "joe"},
                    {"mickel", "mickel"},}, new String[]{"LastName",
                    "FirstName"}));
        final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setVisible(false);
        frame.add(pane);

        JButton btn = new JButton("show");
        frame.add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pane.setVisible(true);

                frame.pack();//this is so the frame will resize after adding pane
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Training();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also for a more reusable `Layout`, why not add all components to a `JPanel`, and add that `JPanel` to the `JFrame`, thus if you ever need to add more stuff its simple.

Comment: +1 for `few things to note:` and image output with description